# Uncaught TypeError: myCheckbox is null, but after I change something in the file and save it, it works normally! (VSCode)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, components, refresh

I have a little but annoying problem.
I tried to write this project to improve my knowledge with React.
I have a checkbox that have to change the theme color into dark mode, but if I refresh the page from the browser (Mozilla Firefox) the checkbox is not recognized, but if I change something in the JSX file (anything, doesn't matter if regards the checkbox or not) and save it, is perfectly recognized and it works!
Can you help me, please?

I leave here the JSX component, I used a console.log to find that that was the problem.

```
import React from "react";
import '../App.css'

const body = document.querySelector('body')
const logo = document.getElementById('logo')
const myCheckbox = document.getElementById('myButton')


if(myCheckbox){
    console.log('yes')
} else {
    console.log('no')
}


function changeMode(){
    if (myCheckbox.checked === true){
        body.style.backgroundColor = '#111111'
        body.style.transition = '1s'
        logo.style.filter = 'invert(100%)'
    } else {
        body.style.backgroundColor = '#ADFFF1'
        body.style.transition = '1s'
        logo.style.filter = 'invert(0%)'
    }
} 

function ButtonMode(){
    return(
        <div id="theme-button">
            <span>
            Dark Theme<input type='checkbox' id="myButton" onClick={changeMode} ></input>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}

   



export default ButtonMode;
```

Here is App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import ButtonMode from './components/colorTheme';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <ButtonMode/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think your code is incomplete. If you could add the part of how you're rendering the checkbox would help.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I added the code in the question!